# Non-informative prior for Poisson/gamma density

Tags: bayesian, prior, uninformative-prior

In the Albert book on Bayesian computation with R, exercise 4.8.5 (p.83), it is suggested to use

$$
p(a, b) \sim (a \times b)^{-2} 
$$

as the non-informative prior for the Poisson/Gamma model:

$$
f(y\,|\, a,b) = \frac{\Gamma(y+a)}{\Gamma(a) \times y!}\frac{b^{a}}{(b+1)^{y+a}}
$$

It does work, but could anyone give me an intuition on that - in other words, why is this prior non-informative?

Comment: What makes you say it does "work" ?

Comment: For both $a$ and $b$ it has a spike at $0$ to allow for very small values and has a Cauchy tail to allow for very large values. The behavior at $0$ makes it improper, but if we  bounded away from $0$ it would still have infinite mean. These are somewhat desirable properties for a "noninformative" prior to have.